# Make Ctrl+S step out of the function before saving

Tags: matlab, debugging, ide, save, keyboard-shortcuts

In MATLAB I sometimes hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and it throws me out of the debugger.

It's so ingrained in my muscle memory to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> whenever I make a change that it's kind-of hard to overcome. OTOH if I step out of the function currently being edited before saving, I can retain at least some of the debug state.

How would one go about the task of reassigning the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut to step out from current file if it is being debugged and is on the call stack and saving it only afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [MEP](https://github.com/GavriYashar/Matlab-Editor-Plugin/) to assign some complex key bindings: create a custom key press callback, then have it do `dbup` and afterwards save somehow.

Comment: @Dev-iL Looks promising, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you asked, but one thing you can do is go to the MATLAB setting and re-enable the warning dialog that exists specifically for this case:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually do want to try to implement the workaround (with MEP if I cannot do without) after I finish with more pressing work.I'll let you know how it goes.